# Why do I get a syntax error in LAG() function?

Tags: mysql

I've made quite some research and cannot find why this doesn't work, could you please help?

I've got a database with a table named 'tl_content' in which I have columns named 'id', 'url' and 'title'. I'm trying to get, for each row, the url of the previous row.

It seems that I should get this with the function LAG().

Here is the code I tried:

```
SELECT url, title, 
LAG(url) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM tl_content
```

But I get the following error message : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY id) FROM tl_content' at line 3".

And I cannot see what's wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Stéphanie.

Comment: I don't think your syntax is correct. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

Comment: @aynber In fact, [the syntax is correct](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20707e381c46172c897382605b1a4fac).  I don't know why the MySQL documentation is suggesting that syntax, but the OP's syntax follows the ANSI standard for analytic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your version of MySQL does not support `LAG`, probably because it is some version earlier than 8+.  You might be able to use a correlated subquery to do the same thing as `LAG`:

```
SELECT
    url,
    title,
    (SELECT url FROM tl_content t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id
     ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) url_lag
FROM tl_content t1;
```

This approach should work fine assuming that the `id` column is unique (i.e. there are never any duplicate `id` values).  If you have a long term need for analytic functions such as `LAG`, then consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: That must be it, I have the 5.7 version. I'll see to do the upgrade. Thanks a lot!